# How to write login form? Please check and help me out

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to write login form. I'm beginner in programming. Please help me out to complete. I don't know how to write.

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtbUsername.Text;
        string password = txtbPassword.Text;

        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NLA-HP;Initial Catalog=GTBDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=dbadmin");

        string query = "select * from login where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "' ";

        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connect);
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: You should always use parameterized queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx

Comment: Think about it logically. So the `SELECT` statement will return the user if the details they entered match what's in the database. If they messed up the username or the password, that `SELECT` statement will return nothing. So you have a condition. You have an `IF` condition to write.

Comment: Also sending a clear text password along the wire is not the wisest move.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" & textBox2.Text != "")  
   {  
        string queryText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 " + 
                           "WHERE username = @Username AND password = @Password";
        using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("your_connection_string"))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);  // cmd is SqlCommand 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);  
            int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result > 0)  
                MessageBox.Show("Loggen In!");  
            else
                MessageBox.Show("User Not Found!");  
        }
    }
```

In the below line of code we are checking that both UserName and Password textbox shouldn't be empty.

> if (textBox1.Text != "" & textBox2.Text != "")

in this part of code we are selecting the number of row it returns from the table that matches both UserName and Password condition.

> string queryText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 " + 
>                                  "WHERE username = @Username AND password = @Password";

Normally it should return 1 as the result. If it returns more that one you should alter the table properties.

when you have a single output value that cannot be defined as a parameter - use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: An answer on a  "tutorial-question" should contain an explanation otherwise it's not helpful.